# PostgreSQL query to select postcodes where where there are no properties

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]I have a two tables:

properties

- uid
- source
- postcode

postcodes

- postcode

What I'm trying to do is make a list of postcodes that have no properties grouping them by source and postcode, I had a partial success with this query:

```
SELECT count(prop.uid), pc.postcode, prop."source"
from properties as prop 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN postcodes as pc
ON prop.postcode = pc.postcode
GROUP BY pc.postcode, prop."source";
```

The problem is that is returning me null sources and what I need is to know which sources have no properties with that postcode.

Need a result like this:

count     postcode       source

0         "AB10 1AB"       zoopla

10        "AB10 1AB"       openrent

0         "AB10 1AB"       spareroom

Comment: If the postcodes have no properteies, there is no corresponding source.  Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want postcodes with no properties, use `not exists`:

```
select pc.*
from postcodes pc
where not exists (select 1 from properties p where p.postcode = pc.postcode);
```

If the postcodes have no properties, there is no corresponding source.

If you want a list of sources/postcode pairs, then use a cross join to get all combinations and the same basic logic:

```
select pc.*, s.source
from postcodes pc cross join
     (select distinct source from properties) s
where not exists (select 1
                  from properties p
                   where p.postcode = pc.postcode and
                         p.source = s.source
                  );
```

If you have a separate table of sources, use that instead of the subquery.

Comment: Yes postcode have no properties, properties have postcode, but, what I need is a result like this: 

count      postcode      source
0             AB10 1AB    zoopla
10             AB10 1AB    openrent

respectively

Comment: Thank you, but, still the same problem, need the ones that count is 0, tried to modify your query like this:

select count(pc.*), s.source, pc.postcode
from postcodes pc cross join
     (select distinct source from properties) s
where not exists (select 1
                  from properties p
                   where p.postcode = pc.postcode and
                         p.source = s.source
                  )
GROUP BY s."source", pc.postcode;

**but still the same issue, the sources with 0 properties are not showing :(**

Comment: @carlosrocha . . . This returns the postcode/source combinations that have no properties.  That seems to be exactly what you want.  Can you set up a db<>fiddle?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't show the source :( already did, thank you so much!

Comment: I was wrong, interpreted wrong your query, thank you so much!!!